Is the property of being a torsor for a smooth affine group scheme detectable on the small étale site?
Let $S$ be a scheme, $G$ a smooth $S$-affine $S$-group scheme, and $X$ an $S$-scheme with a ($S$-linear) $G$-action $\alpha : G\times X\rightarrow X$.
Let $h_X$, $h_G$ be the representable sheaves on the small étale site $S_\text{ét}$ associated to $X,G$ respectively. Suppose $h_X$ is a torsor under $h_G$ (i.e., $h_G(T)$ acts simply transitively on $h_X(T)$ for every étale $T\rightarrow S$). Must $X$ be a $G$-torsor? (i.e., $\alpha\times\mathrm{id} : G\times X\rightarrow X\times X$ is an isomorphism).
If necessary, I'm happy to assume $G$ reductive and that $X$ is $S$-smooth and $S$-affine.
If this is true, a pleasing consequence is that it suffices to check that $h_G(\operatorname{Spec} R)$ is simply transitive on $h_X(\operatorname{Spec} R)$ for strict local rings $R$ of $S$.

This cannot be quite true as stated, already if $G = 1$. Then there is no action and the question is whether $h_X \cong *$ if and only if $X \to S$ is an isomorphism. However, if $S$ is reduced and $X = \mathbf{Spec}S(\mathcal O_S[t]/t^2)$, then $X$ represents the trivial sheaf on $S{\text{ét}}$ since any étale neighbourhood $T \to S$ is reduced. A clear necessary condition is that $X \to S$ is smooth, but I don't think that this improves the situation.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn That's a good point. I'm also happy to assume $X$ is smooth + affine over $S$ (added in edit).

@stupid_question_bot This question is from a while back, so it is likely you have already thought about this, but some simple examples show that in positive characteristic one should not expect this to hold. You can just take $S$ to be the spectrum of an algebraically closed field of characteristic p, and you can let $G=\mathbb{G}_m$ act on itself $X= \mathbb{G}_m$ via the equation $t \cdot x = t^p x$.

Negative result: If the scheme $S$ lives in positive characteristic, then the answer is negative. For an example, take $S = \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and take $G = \mathbb{G}_m$ acting on itself $X = \mathbb{G}_m$ via the equation $t \cdot x = t^p x$.
Positive result: If $S$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-scheme (i.e. it lives in characteristic $0$), then I believe that it is true (this is under all of the assumptions: $X$ is smooth affine over $S$, and $G$ is a connected reductive group scheme over $S$). The argument is a bit intricate (maybe can be simplified). I hope that there are no glaring mistakes.
Assume the "torsorness" at the level of the small étale site of $S$. First, we show the following.
Claim: For all geometric points $\overline{s} \to S$, the fiber $X_{\overline{s}}$ is $G_{\overline{s}}$-equivariantly isomorphic to $G_{\overline{s}}/H$ for some algebraic subgroup $H \subset G_{\overline{s}}$.
We may suppose that $\overline{s}$ is the algebraic closure of the residue field $\kappa(s)$ of its image $s \in S$. Pick a point $x \in X_{\overline{s}}(\overline{s})$. Set $H = \operatorname{Stab}_{G_{\overline{s}}}(x)$. There is a morphism $f:G_{\overline{s}} / H \to X_{\overline{s}}$. A small argument (valid in any characteristic) shows that in order to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to show that $G_{\overline{s}}(\overline{s})$ acts transitively on $X_{\overline{s}}(\overline{s})$ (here we use the smoothness and separatedness of $X_{\overline{s}}$). Hence, we are reduced to showing that $\alpha \times \mathrm{id}: G_{\overline{s}} \times X_{\overline{s}} \to X_{\overline{s}} \times X_{\overline{s}}$ is surjective at the level of $\overline{s}$-points. Choose an $\overline{s}$-point $y$ of $X_{\overline{s}} \times X_{\overline{s}}$. It is define over a finite separable extension of the ground field $\kappa(s)$. By smoothness of $X\times X \to S$, we may find an étale $S$-scheme $T \to S$ equipped with a lift $\overline{s} \to T$ and a point $\widetilde{y}: T \to X \times X$ such that $\overline{s} \to T \to X \times X$ is the point $y$ we started with. Now, by assumption the morphism on $T$-points $G(T) \times X(T) \to X(T) \times X(T)$ is surjective, and so there is a $T$-point $ \widetilde{z}: T \to G \times X$ that maps to $\widetilde{y}$. The composition $\overline{s} \to T \xrightarrow{\widetilde{z}} G \times X$ maps to the original $y$, and we conclude the desired surjectivity. This concludes the proof of the claim.
Now we use a hammer. Consider the quotient stack $[X/G] \to S$. By affinness of $X$ and (linear) reductivity of $G$, this has a good moduli space $[X/G] \to M \to S$ in the sense of Alper. The morphism $M \to S$ is flat affine and of finite type, because the stack was flat and of finite type over $S$ and $M$ is the relative spectrum of the sheaf of invariant rings. The formation of $M$ commutes with arbitrary base-change on $S$, and it follows from the claim that for all geometric points $\overline{s} \to S$ we have that the base-change $M_{\overline{s}} \to \overline{s}$ is an isomorphism. Hence, $M \to S$ is an isomorphism.
Now we use a double-hammer.  Since the stack $[X/G] \to S$ is smooth, the etale local structure of good moduli space morphisms (see Section 10.2 in Alper, Hall, and Rydh - The étale local structure of algebraic stacks) tells us that, after replacing $S$ with an étale cover, there is a linearly reductive group $H$ over $S$ and an $H$-equivariant vector bundle $E \to S$ such that $[X/G] \cong [V/H]$. By our fiberwise claim, we see that $V$ must be the zero vector bundle. Hence, we upgrade our claim to conclude that, étale-locally on $S$, we have a $G$-equivariant isomorphism $X \cong G/H$ for some linearly reductive closed subgroup scheme $H \subset G$, which is smooth because the characteristic is 0.
Now, if $H$ was not trivial, then we would have some nonidentity section of $H$ over some $S$-scheme $T$ that would stabilize the tautological $S$-section of $X \cong G/H$. Since $H$ is smooth, we may even take $T$ to be étale. This would contradict the assumption of simple transitivity of the action on étale $S$-schemes. We conclude that $H$ is trivial, and hence $X$ is a torsor.

Upon further thought, I think that may avoid the (very nontrivial) local structure theorems in my answer and even prove a more general result in characteristic $0$. I post this potential argument as a separate answer, since merging everything in one answer would be a bit bulky.
Here is the claim.
Statement. Let $S$ be a Noetherian scheme over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $G \to S$ be a finite type smooth group scheme, and let $X \to S$ be a smooth scheme. Suppose that $X$ is equipped with an action of $G$ such that the induced morphism $\alpha \times id: G \times_S X \to X \times_S X$ is an isomorphism of sheaves on the small etale site of $S$. Then, $X$ is a $G$-torsor.
To prove this, first we use the same claim as before. The proof is the same as in the other answer. I state here as two lemmas for completeness:
Lemma 1. Let $s \in S$ be a point with residue field $\kappa(s)$, and let $\overline{s}= \mathrm{Spec}(\overline{\kappa(s)}) \to S$ be the geometric point corresponding to a choice of algebraic closure of $\kappa(s)$. Then, the morphism $G_{\overline{s}} \times X_{\overline{s}} \to X_{\overline{s}} \times X_{\overline{s}}$ is surjective at the level of $\overline{s}$-points.
Proof of Lemma 1. Choose an $\overline{s}$-point $y$ of $X_{\overline{s}} \times X_{\overline{s}}$. It is defined over a finite separable extension of the ground field $\kappa(s)$. By smoothness of $X\times X \to S$, we may find an étale $S$-scheme $T \to S$ equipped with a lift $\overline{s} \to T$ and a point $\widetilde{y}: T \to X \times X$ such that $\overline{s} \to T \to X \times X$ is the point $y$ we started with. Now, by assumption the morphism on $T$-points $G(T) \times X(T) \to X(T) \times X(T)$ is surjective, and so there is a $T$-point $ \widetilde{z}: T \to G \times X$ that maps to $\widetilde{y}$. The composition $\overline{s} \to T \xrightarrow{\widetilde{z}} G \times X$ maps to the original $y$, and we conclude the desired surjectivity. QED
Lemma 2. For all geometric points $\overline{s} \to S$, the fiber $X_{\overline{s}}$ is $G_{\overline{s}}$-equivariantly isomorphic to $G_{\overline{s}}/H$ for some closed subgroup $H \subset G_{\overline{s}}$.
Proof of Lemma 2.
We may suppose that $\overline{s}$ is the algebraic closure of the residue field $\kappa(s)$ of its image $s \in S$. Pick a point $x \in X_{\overline{s}}(\overline{s})$. Set $H = \operatorname{Stab}_{G_{\overline{s}}}(x)$. There is an induced morphism $f:G_{\overline{s}} / H \to X_{\overline{s}}$. By transitivity of the action of $G_{\overline{s}}$ on $\overline{s}$-points and the definition of $H$, we see that the preimage of every closed point of $X_{\overline{s}}$ is a reduced point. Note that $X_{\overline{s}}$ is smooth by assumption, and that $G_{\overline{s}}$ is smooth by descent. Since $G_{\overline{s}}$ is of finite type, the morphism of $f$ is of finite type, and hence by Chevalleys theorem the image is constructible. Since the image of $f$ contains all closed points, at least one of the (smooth integral) components of $G_{\overline{s}}/H$ dominates a (smooth integral) component of $X_{\overline{s}}$ (the image contains an open subset). By translation, every (smooth integral) component of $G_{\overline{s}}/H$ dominates a component of $X_{\overline{s}}$. Now we are in the context to apply (locally) the miracle flatness theorem: we have a dominant morphism f smooth integral schemes with all fibers points. So we have that $G_{\overline{s}}/H \to X_{\overline{s}}$ is flat, hence etale by the assumption on the fibers at closed points. The openness of $f$ and the surjectivity on closed points imply a posteriori that $X_{\overline{s}}$ is also finite type and the morphism $f$ is surjective. Since it induces an injection on closed points, one can see that it $f$ indeed a (surjective) open immersion, hence an isomorphism. QED
Lemma 3. The quotient stack $[X/G]$ is a gerbe over $S$.
Proof of Lemma 3. We first show that $[X/G]$ is a gerbe over an $S$-algebraic space $Y$. By https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06QJ, to show this it suffices to prove that the relative inertia of $[X/G] \to S$ is flat. This would follow from the morphism $G \times_S X \to X \times_S X$ being flat. By the fiberwise criterion for flatness https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/039E, it suffices to check that for all $s \in S$, we have that the induced morphism on $s$-fibers $G_s \times X_s \to X_s \times X_s$ is flat. We may even check this after passing to geometric points $\overline{s} \to S$, and by Lemma 1 we are reduced to checking flatness of the corresponding morphism when $X_{\overline{s}} = G_{\overline{s}}/H$, which is true.
Now consider the factorization $[X/G] \to Y \to S$, where the first morphism is a gerbe. Since $[X/G] \to Y$ is flat and $[X/G] \to S$ is smooth, it follows that $Y \to S$ is smooth. Furthermore, the formation of $Y$ commutes with base change on $S$, and over every geometric point $\overline{s} \to S$ we have that the fiber $Y_{\overline{s}}$ is $\overline{s}$ (because the fiber $[X_{\overline{s}}/G_{\overline{s}}]$ is $BH$, which is a gerbe over $\overline{s}$). Hence we see that $Y \to S$ is a universally injective etale morphism, and hence it is an open immersion. Since $Y \to S$ is also surjective, we conclude that $Y=S$. QED
Proof of the Statement. At this point we know that $[X/G] \to S$ is a gerbe, and by the smoothness of $X$ it admits sections etale locally on $S$. After passing to an etale cover of $S$, we may fix a section of $X \to S$ and we obtain an isomorphism $[X/G] \cong BH$ for some flat subgroup scheme $H \subset G$ (the stabilizer of the section). At this point, to conclude that $X$ is a $G$-torsor we just need to show that $H \to S$ is the trivial group scheme. Since we are in characteristic $0$, the fibers of $H \to S$ are automatically regular, and hence $H \to S$ is smooth. Suppose for the sake of contradicton that $H \to S$ was nontrivial. Then there would be an etale $S$-scheme $T \to S$ and a $T$ point $h \in H(T)$ that is not the identity. Note that $h$ would fix the corresponding distinguished section $x \in X(T)$ induced by the trivial section $S \to BH$ under the isomorphism $[X/G] \cong BH$. Viewing $h \in G(T)$, this would contradict the freeness of the action of $G(T)$ on $X(T)$.QED
Edited: Added necessary hypothesis that $G$ is of finite type, needed in the proof of Lemma 2. Otherwise the statement is false (take $S$ the spectrum of an algebraically closed field $k$, take $X=\mathbb{A}^1$, and let $G$ be disjoint copies of the $k$-points of $\mathbb{A}^1$ acting by translation). I added more details to the proof of Lemma 2 to be extra careful; non quasi-compact things are subtle.
